# org.apache.kylin.job.exception.ExecuteException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/typeinfo/TypeInfo

Tags: hadoop, hive, kylin

I find similar error on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-2511

env:
hadoop-2.7.1
hbase-1.3.2
apache-hive-2.1.1-bin
apache-kylin-1.6.0-hbase1.x-bin

I've tried copy all the hive libs to kylin, but get another ERROR.

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/typeinfo/TypeInfo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing class should be in hive-exec-.jar; Check and debug the "bin/find-hive-dependency.sh" to see why it wasn't able to locate this jar from your server. You can manually add it to the "hive_exec_path" variable.

BTW, Kylin 1.6 is quite old, try to upgrade to a 2.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Why you just try the method mentioned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-2511. You'd better prepare the env according to the document of v16. It is better for using the latest version of Kylin. It has more feature and fixes some bugs.